# Center Aligning an anchor element in a header

Tags: html, css, center

```css
/* Global */
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Header */
header {
 width: 100vw;
 padding: 1.5em;

 background-color: #ccc;
}

header > a {

 background-color: yellow;
}

/* Navigation */
nav {
 display: inline-block;

 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Saad Al-Sabbagh | Web Developer</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 </head>

 <body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header>

   <!-- Navigation -->
   <nav>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">Expertise</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </nav>

   <a href="#">Saad Al-Sabbagh</a>

  </header>

 </body>

</html>
```

I want to center the immediate child under the header, that's the anchor element outside the nav.

The header is full width, and the navigation is inline-block, but when I am trying to do text-align: center; it doesn't seem to work.

I came to the conclusion that the property only works on block level elements, and I am sure that the conclusion is true.

What do you suggest in order to center the text in the middle?

Comment: Where do you want the logo to be?

Comment: @Roy it's not a logo per se, but just a text that acts as a logo, but anyways I want it to be center aligned.

Comment: @SaadAl-Sabbagh [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/dgaynmxp/1/ ] looking something like this??

Comment: @MostafaBaezid No. not really TBH, that makes the anchor element that's yellow under the red one I want the red one floated left and yellow aligned center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what you wanted. I made the navigation a list and put a class on the 'logo'.

```
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This will keep the text centered and only the text is clickable, not the whole line/block.

```css
/* Global */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
/* Header */

header {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
header > a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
/* Navigation */

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
.list,
.list-item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list {
  list-style: none;
}
.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Saad Al-Sabbagh | Web Developer</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Expertise</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">Saad Al-Sabbagh</a>
    </div>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately that still puts the anchor on another line which I don't want, I want something like this one as a rough example ( http://hej.ch/ )

Comment: @SaadAl-Sabbagh What they did over there is that they `text-align: center` the text in the middle and they `position: absolute` the menu to the top left corner.

Comment: @SaadAl-Sabbagh I updated the code snippet to reflect the website.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the anchor in a div and set the below style for it.

In HTML:

```
<div id="centeredAfterNav"><a href="#">Saad Al-Sabbagh</a></div>
```

In CSS:

```
#centeredAfterNav {
    display: inline;
    /*left-margin: 100px;*/ /* Width of left aligned nav, to center in the remaining space */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That'll center align everything, I want the anchor element outside of the nav and inside of the header to be center aligned only and the nav to be left aligned, which is now. I don't want to center align everything.

Comment: I updated the answer to center the link after the nav.

Comment: Never use an ID when it's not needed. Why do you need the `margin-left`?

Comment: It's an example. The margin left is used to center the link regarding the width of the left aligned nav.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help as I don't want the link to be centered AFTER the nav, as a rough example this website does it properly ( http://hej.ch/ )

Comment: In that case, remove the margin-left offset (example updated).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Turns out  needed to be absolute ..

```
nav {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 18px;
padding-left: 21px;
text-align: left;
width: 500px;
}
```